# Notation: Apply summation to elements of a vector

Tags: summation, notation

Suppose I have vector $\boldsymbol{x}=(x_{1i}, x_{2i})$ and I would like to sum each vector element over $i=1,\dotsb,n$, so my new vector should look like this:
($\sum_{i=1}^n x_{1i}, \sum_{i=1}^n x_{2i}$). Since my actual vector $\boldsymbol{x}$ contains more than two elements, I was wondering whether there is a short and clear notation for taking the sum of each element without taking the sum of elements.

Comment: You could define a "one" vector $\boldsymbol{u} = (1,1, \ldots)$ and then take the dot product $\boldsymbol{x} \cdot \boldsymbol{u}$.

Comment: @Matti I don't think that solves the problem, but something similar with, say, multiplying the row vector x by an appropriate $2n\times2$ matrix would.